OpenCV 4.5 produces wrong eigen vectors
So I rejoiced in the easy installation of opencv under WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux),
Ubuntu:
apt-get install libopencv-dev

Following this up with dpkg -s libopencv-dev | grep Version answered me
Version: 4.5.4+dfsg-9Ubuntu4. I am interested in eigen vectors.
Nothing evil, real valued eigen values will do nicely (however, complex ones would also be welcome).
I wrote a CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(testcv)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(testcv testcv.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testcv ${OpenCV_LIBS})

And the following test program testcv.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        float numbers[] =
              { 0, 2,
                1, 0 };
        Mat A = Mat(2,2,CV_32F,numbers);
        Mat eigen_vals, eigen_vecs;
        eigen(A, eigen_vals, eigen_vecs);
        cout << "A: " << A << endl <<
          "eigen_vals: " << eigen_vals << endl <<
          "eigen_vecs: : " << eigen_vecs << endl <<
          "Done." << endl;
        return 0;
}

Finally, saying
cmake .
make
./testcv

got me
A: [0, 2;
 1, 0]
eigen_vals: [0.99999994;
 -0.99999994]
eigen_vecs: : [0.70710677, 0.70710677;
 -0.70710677, 0.70710677]
Done.

Honestly? That is just wrong! For comparison, my octave results:
>> A
A =

   0   2
   1   0

>> lambda
lambda =

Diagonal Matrix

   1.4142        0
        0  -1.4142

>> B
B =

   0.8165  -0.8165
   0.5774   0.5774

>> A*B
ans =

   1.1547   1.1547
   0.8165  -0.8165

What am I doing wrong here, in such a simple call to such a simple interface?

Found my own answer by reading the docs a little closer: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html
bool cv::eigen (InputArray src,
  OutputArray eigenvalues, OutputArray eigenvectors=noArray())


Calculates eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix.

Also answering the optional "complex" part of the question (real-valued, symmetric matrices yield real-valued eigenvalues).
Note: Also be wary that eigenvectors are stored row-wise by cv::eigen(..). So the first row is the first eigenvector.

haha this is awful. they added eigenNonSymmetric because of that. OpenCV needs another clean break in its API. IDK if that'll ever happen again. those names need fixing, and the symmetric variant should check if it's been fed a non-symmetric matrix.
